# Mapping a relationship between a subclass and a regular entity, and mapping a relation between two subclasses

Tags: entity-relationship

[image: EER Diagram]

I want to know how to map the relation between the landlord and property as well as the relation between the student and the landlord.
I know how to map a one to many relation. In this case, it's the relation between the landlord and the property. But since landlord is a subclass of Person, and uses the primary key of person, which is nic, as the primary key of the landlord, should I take the nic as the foreign key to the relation between landlord and property?
So that;

Property(**Idno**,Street,City,Fee,Amount,NIC)

Should it be like this?

And in the other relationship, which is the relationship between Student and Landlord, since both are sub classes of the entity Person and both are having NIC as their primary key because of it being the primary key of the superclass, how should that be mapped?

student(**NIC**,STID,Gender,DOB,NIC)

This isn't correct imo. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should take NIC. That's because it's the primary key and the only unique identifier. It's not wise to create another key or something like that.

Now about the landlord and student relation there should be none directly to them. Think it like a database you would have a table that are the properties that have 2 foreign keys. The landlord and the current student it is rented to. So I think there should be a relationship betweeen the student and property. Not between the landlord and the student.

Comment: Thank you  very much. I agree, there is not point of having a relation ship between the landlord and the student because with a student-property relationship, student indirectly makes a relationship with the landlord via property.